# Showing start and end times in Google Calendars

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendars is it possible to show start and end times of events, without having to write them in the description?

Answer (score 3):

Switching to `Day`, `Week`, `7 Days`, or `agenda` view, all will display the times.